# Symfony2, doctrine2, can I return an array as a response in the controller?

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I've got an embedded controller that takes in a parameter and retrieves from the db.

```
{% for key, value in boxes %}
{{ render(controller('ABundle:Reports:getBox', { 'boxnum' : value.boxnum })) }}
<tr>
     <td>{{ value.boxnum }}</td>
     <td>{{ value.boxname }}</td>
     <td>( # of total box )</td>
     <td>( # of available box)</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Controller:

```
public function getBox($boxnum) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ABundle:MainBoxes');
    $getbox = $em->availBoxes($boxnum);

    return new Response(array('getbox' => $getbox)); // this doesn't work obviously...
}
```

I want the results to retrieve db and print it out in a loop. Something like

```
<tr>
     <td>{{ value.boxnum }}</td>
     <td>{{ value.boxname }}</td>
     <td>{{ getbox.totalbox }}</td>
     <td>{{ getbox.availbox }}</td>
 </tr>
```

I'm getting an error for the wrong response return. It's not allowing me to return an array?

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The Response 
content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "array" given.")
```

Comment: Just have Controller::getBox render and return the html.  You can even pass the template name as an argument to getBox if you want.

Comment: @Cerad I tried rendering the same template but it's giving me the entire html, including the headers and navigation menu.

Comment: Make a template just for rendering the boxData.  Basically just the twig for your record.

Comment: If you really just want the data then make a twig extension and do your query there.  You will want to inject your MainBoxes repository.  But render(controller is probably what you want.

Comment: @Cerad your suggestion of making another template worked, but it seems a bit unnecessary just for a little bit of data. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cerad can you direct me to the information for twig extension??

Comment: Cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Dividing larger templates into smaller, easier to understand and change, files is a good thing.  You could also change getBox to getBoxes and have render all the records thus cutting down on your twig code a bit and improving performance.

Comment: You could also call $repo->getBoxes in your controller and just pass the results to your template.  That really would be the best approach.

Comment: Finally, you could pass the repository to your template.  {% set boxes = repo.availBoxes[value.boxnum] %}.  However, in most cases it is better to push data into templates and not pull it from templates.